# Smartmontools self-test log giving wrong information

Tags: ssd, scheduled-tasks, smart

I have scheduled all the computers to run a short test every day with smartd but I'm having issues with two SSD's.

I see multiple instances of the scheduled test. One run completed; others are still pending with various times remaining.

Is this because it's a SSD? Is it safe to ignore or the tests are really pending?

I am using windows 10 and the latest version of smartmontools.

[image: screenshot1]

[image: screenshot2]

edit:

I see the same behavior if I manually start a test on those SSD's. (with smartctl -t short /dev/sda)

Just started a new short test, and I see 3 instances of the same test; a completed one and other two stuck at 10% and 50% remaining time.

[screenshot3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jglN2.png)

But, looking at the self-test execution status it doesn't appear to be any test in progress.

[screenshot4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhEcS.png)

Comment: Nope, smartmonools and smartd work AOK on other SSDs.   Will smartd run OK manually on those problematic drives ? Kill the process(es) if still running, and retry. Also, since smartmontools runs on multiple OS, please advise which OS and version/release number you are using. Click on edit above at left to update your original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer I received from smartmontools support:

> Regarding the self-test log: Broken self-test logs are a typical drive
>   firmware flaw which cannot be fixed by smartmontools. A quick search
>   on my archive of smartctl outputs show same behavior for: ADATA_SP300
>   ADATA_SP550 ADATA_XM11_128GB Corsair_Force_GS INTEL_SSDSA2VP020G3
>   INTEL_SSDSC2CW180A3 INTEL_SSDSC2KW240H6 MAXTOR_STM3160215AS
>   Mushkin_MKNSSDCL60GB-DX SAMSUNG_SP0842N SanDisk_SDSSDX240GG25
>   Seagate+ST3200826AS Seagate+ST94813A

Guess we can also add WDC WDS120G2G0B-00EPW0 to that list.